# Sonarque does not execute custom quality profile

Tags: ant, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I have Sonar 4.5 running and Jenkins does execute an ANT task comprising org.sonar.ant.SonarTask
Initially with the build-in Sonar rules quality profile "sonar way" everything was running perfectly well. After introducing my company's custom quality profile there are "**0 issues in 322k lines of code**". Of course I know from the code this is NOT true.

The output of the ant task looks OK. The sonar log file does not issue any errors/warnings. The import of the quality profile via the admin site did not raise any errors/warning and the new rules are also visible on the admin site.

Any ideas of how to proceed are welcome.

Comment: Is it possible that you companies custom profile has a very permissive set or rules defined? I speculate that Sonarqube might have found 0 issues with your code... Just a thought.

Comment: No, as I wrote above.

Comment: Can you please update your question to provide the name of the new quality profile and the analysis log as well?

Comment: The name of the profile contains the company's name, which I must not disclose. Do you need the name or the profile itself? Which analysis log do you need? I have some output from the ant task. The sonar.log does not contain anything at the time of the last analysis.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 things that you can try: 
1. sonar.profile= name_of_your_new_profile while running the analysis. 
2. Associate the project to the new Profile by going to the dashboard and setting it under Project Configuration > Quality profiles > Select the new profile for the language that you are trying to analyse.